# VB.NET DataGridView - doesn't set cell.backgroundcolor

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, xml-parsing, cell

I am parsing an XML file and want to set the background color of each cell in a DataGridView to the string between the `<cell>` and `</cell>` tags of the XML file.

This is the structure of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<Project StartTime="7" EndTime="12">
  <Tabs>
    <Page1 type="Tab">
      <Grids>
        <DataGridView>
          <row> 'first row in DataGridView
            <task name="task1" backcolor="White" /> 'first column on grid
            <cell>White</cell> 'second column (contains a button)
            <cell>Red</cell> 'third column
            <cell>White</cell> 'fourth column
            <cell>White</cell> 'fifth column
                 .  .  .
```

And this is the code I am using to set the cell's color:

```
If reader.Name = "cell" Then
 Grid.Rows(i).Cells(i).Style.BackColor = Color.FromName("Color." & reader.ReadElementString("cell"))
End If
```

However, the program doesn't set the color at all and each cell still has White as background color.

Has anyone else come across this issue and what is the best way to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working with the following code:

```
 Grid.Rows(i).Cells(i).BackColor = Color.FromName(reader.ReadElementString("cell"))
```

Also, make sure `reader.ReadElementString("cell")` is returning the correct name of the color.

Hope it helps!

PS: No "Style" and no "Color."